# Calculating volumes and surface areas (Calc 1)

Tags: calculus, volume, surface-integrals

I am having some trouble understanding why the integrals setup for finding surfaces consider the slant of the function, whereas while calculating volumes we don't bother with them.

[Setup diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEqur.jpg)

Consider the setup in the link.

If I were to rotate the graph about the x-axis, and then try to write the equation for infinitesimal surface area, I would end up with

$$∆Surface = 2y * \sqrt(1 + (\frac{∆y}{∆x})^2) * ∆x$$

Whereas for Volume I would have,

$$∆Volume = y^2 * ∆x$$

In case of volume why don't we consider the slant, or why isn't the formula for infinitesimal volume

$$∆Volume = y^2 * ∆x + \frac{1}{2} * ∆y * ∆x * 2y$$ where the additional part would be the volume due to the enlarged triangle in the image rotated about the x - axis.

Comment: For both of your two expressions for $\Delta\text{Volume}$ the limit $$\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{\Delta\text{Volume}}{\Delta x}$$ is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the fundamental theorem of calculus,
$$
V(b)=\int_a^b V'(x)\,dx,
$$
to compute the volume. For both of your two expressions for $\Delta V$ the limit
$$
\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{\Delta V}{\Delta x}=V'(x)
$$
is the same.

Comment: Thank you for helping out, I got seriously confused thinking about infinitesimals. I used to set up integrals directly by replacing $\Delta x$ with $dx$, seems like it doesn't work in all cases :)